# HTML Form Align

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get the content of my div to align, everything will center apart from the contents of the table. The title will center along with the login button.

CSS:

```
.center {
margin:auto;
width: 50%;
border:3px solid #8AC007;
padding: 10px;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
font-family:'Century Gothic';
text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="center">   
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h3>
  Login Page</h3>
<table >
  <tr>
    <td>
      E-mail address:</td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="UserEmail" runat="server" /></td>
    <td>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
        ControlToValidate="UserEmail"
        Display="Dynamic" 
        ErrorMessage="Required" 
        runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Password:</td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="UserPass" TextMode="Password" 
         runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
        ControlToValidate="UserPass"
        ErrorMessage="Cannot be empty." 
        runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Remember me?</td>
    <td>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="Persist" runat="server" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<asp:Button ID="Submit1" OnClick="Logon_Click" Text="Login" 
   runat="server" />
<p>
  <asp:Label ID="Msg" ForeColor="red" runat="server" />
</p>
</form>
    </div>
```

I've tried text align on the table as well with no luck

[image]

Comment: Can u show me some image to align contents

Comment: Picture added for ref

Comment: Add align="center" attribute to your code

Comment: On a side note, you should NEVER use tables for layout. That practice has been actively discouraged for over 10 years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `margin: 0 auto` to the table element. Currently your `margin: auto` only centers the form but inside it the table is aligned to the left because of the default behavior of contents to start from left.

*Don't try to use tables for layout purpose, although you can use them for tabular data.*

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #8AC007;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto; /* Add */
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h3>
  Login Page</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          E-mail address:</td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="UserEmail" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="UserEmail" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" runat="server" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Password:</td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="UserPass" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="UserPass" ErrorMessage="Cannot be empty." runat="server" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Remember me?</td>
        <td>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="Persist" runat="server" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="Submit1" OnClick="Logon_Click" Text="Login" runat="server" />
    <p>
      <asp:Label ID="Msg" ForeColor="red" runat="server" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you just what I wanted.